# Two times the same 6 lines of code

Tags: php, function, scope

I have two times in my PHP code the same 5 lines of code:

```
do_something1();
$myvar1 = something1();
do_something_else2();
$myvar2 = something2();
do_something_else3();
$myvar3 = something3();

// another code
// ...
// another code

do_something1();
$myvar1 = something1();
do_something_else2();
$myvar2 = something2();
do_something_else3();
$myvar3 = something3();
```

Would someone like this be possible to avoid repetition?

```
@BEGINNING BLAH
do_something1();
$myvar1 = something1();
do_something_else2();
$myvar2 = something2();
do_something_else3();
$myvar3 = something3();
@END BLAH

// another code
// ...
// another code

@INSERT BLAH
```

Of course, I could define a new `function`, but then here, I would have to define `global` variables (should I pre-define the variables before calling the function itself with `global`?), etc.

That's why I was looking if something shorter than a `function` existed in such situations, like a PREPROCESSOR copy/paste.

Comment: I think you have to show us your **real** code to be able to tell you how you can optimize it

Comment: @Rizier123 here is the code which needs to be called twice : http://pastebin.com/ERVmMsWZ. This code exports $pageheader, $pagecontent, $pagetitle and $linkurl.

Comment: So your problem is to return the variables ?

Comment: @Rizier123 not really: my problem (it's not really a problem) is to know if something else than functions exist to do that...

Comment: Then I don't think there is anything else than wrap it in a function and either use by reference or return the variables. PHP isn't magic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a lot of acceptable solution, but there is one :

```
// Here is the function doing the repetitive work
function blah(){
    do_something1();
    $myvar1 = something1();
    do_something_else2();;
    $myvar2 = something2();
    do_something_else3();
    $myvar3 = something3();
    return array($myvar1,$myvar2,$myvar3);
}

// Now for the usage matching your above case

list($myvar1,$myvar2,$myvar3) = blah();    

// another code
// ...
// another code

list($myvar1,$myvar2,$myvar3) = blah();
```

List can be a really useful php function - http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php

Comment: *Of course, I could define a new function, but then here, I would have to define global variables* I think OP is doing stuff which he doesn't show us here!

Comment: @Rizier123 I think he meant using global because he didn't have a clue on assigning 3 variables with only the return of one function, which is achieved with list here :)

Comment: ^ That would be a pretty good guess if you're right! (I still guess that OP has code which he doesn't show us which is a bit different than this one here)

Comment: @b.enoit.be yes I had ni idea about how to do it :) By the way here is the code which needs to be called twice : pastebin.com/ERVmMsWZ. This code exports $pageheader, $pagecontent, $pagetitle and $linkurl.

Comment: True, but I wanted to know if it's possible to avoid writing a `function`, just to know if there is some magical places I haven't been before inside PHP world :)

Comment: As said, plenty of possible way to design it. You could also put the code in a `path/to/file.php` and then `include 'path/to/file.php'` each time. 
Or use a class, and do not write setter but only getter so the values cannot be changed. Actually, if you need to recalculate those variable a second time you do have a design flaw somewhere. You should be able to get them once and for good and then maybe copy them some place else if you need to compute on it.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this? just put your code where $var1 is and change the number in the middle of the for line to the number of iterations you want it to do.

```
for ($i=1; $i<=2; $i++) {

$var1 = "";

}
```

Comment: No no, it's not this. I have some code in the middle see `// another code`, and the two places where the same code is called, is far one from the other.

Comment: then write a function that you can call in those two places or put the code in another file and include it in those two places. both methods will work.